# MongoDB automatically removes documents

Tags: c#, mongodb

So I've been using MongoDB with C# Driver (quite new to it). I am able to save data into the collection and can verify via cmd. But after the debugger is stopped on Visual Studio, mongo keeps the entries in the collection for a bit after a while, when i run a count again, the documents are gone. I could not find much help with this anywhere. Is there something I am doing wrong? [screenshot of mongo count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hOki.jpg)

Also, when i look at the folder where the database are stored, my db has multiple files with the extension .0, .1, .2 etc. So i'm guessing the data is in there but somehow I am unable to read it.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Edit: this is the stats on the [collection](https://imgur.com/yWdQFe9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start your mongod, did you use --dbpath  to point your database to a certain folder like [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/)?

```
mkdir my_db_dir
ls -al (to verify that you have succeeded in creating my_db_dir/)
mongod --dbpath my_db_dir
```

Comment: When i run Mongod --dbpath i get this error ` ERROR: dbpath (\data\db\) does not exist.`. I tried specifying the folder where mongo is installed but it still gives the same error.

Comment: I added another screenshot after i got mongo --dbpath running. The storage size on the collection is about a gig, but still can't see any records

Comment: Where your db is does not necessarily have to be where you installed mongo. Did you try creating the directory before using it by 'mkdir' ? Please see the edited answer.

Comment: I manged to get Mongod to start. But the records were still not there. I've added another 18000 records to try replicate the issue but so far so good.